# perl module vCard

Tags: perl, vcf-vcard

I am new to perl but had some success for my first script.
I would like to use the module "vCard".

OK, as requested, 
full script + file + output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::vCard::Node;
use Text::vCard;
use Text::vFile;
use vCard;
use Glib;
use Gtk2 '-init';
use Getopt::Long;
#  _      __        _       _     _      
#   \    / /       (_)     | |   | |     
#  \ \  / /_ _ _ __ _  __ _| |__ | | ___ 
#   \ \/ / _` | '__| |/ _` | '_ \| |/ _ \
#    \  / (_| | |  | | (_| | |_) | |  __/
#     \/ \__,_|_|  |_|\__,_|_.__/|_|\___|
#                                        
#                                        
### variables block
my $self='';
my $av_std_VERSION;
my $av_loc_FILENAME;
my $av_loc_VCARD;
my $av_ADDRESSES;
my $av_NODES;
my $tmp_av_STRING;
my $tmp_av_FN;
my $tmp_av_FILE;
my $tmp_av_RETURN;

# option parameters
my $av_pospar_DEBUG='';
my $av_pospar_VERBOSE='';
my $av_pospar_LOGGING='';
my $av_pospar_TEST='';
my $av_pospar_VERSION='';

#dialogelemente
my $av_WINDOW;
my $av_BUTTON;
my $av_HBOX;
my $av_VBOX;
my $av_TEXTBOX1;
my $av_LABEL1;

#filehandler
my $fh_av_VCARD;

#  ______                _   _                 
#    ____|              | | (_)                
#   |__ _   _ _ __   ___| |_ _  ___  _ __  ___ 
#    __| | | | '_ \ / __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \/ __|
#   |  | |_| | | | | (__| |_| | (_) | | | \__ \
#  _|   \__,_|_| |_|\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|___/
#                                              
#                                              
### functions commands block
sub schluss
{
     Gtk2->main_quit();
     exit (0);
}
sub auswertung
{
     $tmp_av_STRING = $av_TEXTBOX1->get_text();
     Gtk2->main_quit();
}

sub av_help
{
    print "Benutzung:\n";
    print "xxx.pl [-d, --debug] [-f, --file <filename>] [-h, --help] [-t, --test] [-v, --verbose] [-V, --version]\n";
    print "Bedeutung der Optionen:\n";
    print "-d, --debug := debug on\n";
    print "-f, --file := dateiname einer existierenden .vcf-datei deren Werte eingelesen werden sollen\n";
    print "-h, --help := diese Information\n";
    print "-l, --logging := log all output to file in /var/userlog/\n";
    print "-t, --test := test mode on\n";
    print "-v, --verbose, -d, --debug := verbose on + debug on\n";
    print "-V, --version := Version wird ausgegeben\n";
}
#  _____                                _   _             
#    __ \                              | | (_)            
#   |__) | __ ___ _ __   __ _ _ __ __ _| |_ _  ___  _ __  
#    ___/ '__/ _ \ '_ \ / _` | '__/ _` | __| |/ _ \| '_ \ 
#   |   | | |  __/ |_) | (_| | | | (_| | |_| | (_) | | | |
#  _|   |_|  \___| .__/ \__,_|_|  \__,_|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|
#                | |                                      
#                |_|                                      
### preparation commands block

GetOptions ("d" => \$av_pospar_DEBUG,    # debug
              "debug"   => \$av_pospar_DEBUG,      # debug
              "h"   => \&av_help,      # help
              "help"   => \&av_help,      # help
              "f=s"   => \$av_loc_FILENAME,      # file
              "file=s"   => \$av_loc_FILENAME,      # file
              "l"   => \$av_pospar_LOGGING,      # logging
              "logging"   => \$av_pospar_LOGGING,      # logging
              "t"   => \$av_pospar_TEST,      # test
              "test"   => \$av_pospar_TEST,      # test
              "v"   => \$av_pospar_VERBOSE,      # verbose
              "verbose"  => \$av_pospar_VERBOSE,   # verbose
#              "V"   => \$av_pospar_VERSION,      # version
              "version"  => \$av_pospar_VERSION)   # version
  or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

print "debug: $av_pospar_DEBUG\n";
print "file: $av_loc_FILENAME\n";
print "logging: $av_pospar_LOGGING\n";
print "test: $av_pospar_TEST\n";
print "verbose: $av_pospar_VERBOSE\n";
print "version: $av_pospar_VERSION\n";
print "alle optionen: @ARGV\n";

#  __  __       _         _____                  
#    \/  |     (_)       |  __ \                 
#   \  / | __ _ _ _ __   | |__) | __ ___   ___   
#   |\/| |/ _` | | '_ \  |  ___/ '__/ _ \ / __|  
#   |  | | (_| | | | | | | |   | | | (_) | (__ _ 
#  _|  |_|\__,_|_|_| |_| |_|   |_|  \___/ \___(_)
#                                                
#                                                
### main procedure

$av_loc_VCARD = vCard->new;

$av_loc_VCARD->load_file($av_loc_FILENAME);
print "return: $!\n";

$tmp_av_STRING = $av_loc_VCARD->as_string;
print "$tmp_av_STRING\n";

#  ______           _   _____                  
# |  ____|         | | |  __ \                 
# | |__   _ __   __| | | |__) | __ ___   ___   
# |  __| | '_ \ / _` | |  ___/ '__/ _ \ / __|  
# | |____| | | | (_| | | |   | | | (_) | (__ _ 
# |______|_| |_|\__,_| |_|   |_|  \___/ \___(_)
#                                              
#                                              
### end procedure
exit (0);
```

Here you find the vcard used:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N;LANGUAGE=de:mySurname;myFirstname
FN:myFirstname mySurname
ORG:myCompany GmbH
TEL;TYPE=work:+49 (0000) 123456
ADR;TYPE=work:;;Strasse 1;Ortschaft arbeit;;56789;Deutschland
ADR;TYPE=home;PREF:;;Privatstrasse 17;Privatortschaft;;00111;Deutschland
EMAIL:info@a.de
URL:www.a.de
END:VCARD
```

And that's the output:

```
./av_perl_10.pl -v -f test_input.vcf
debug: 
file: test_input.vcf
logging: 
test: 
verbose: 1
version: 
alle optionen: 
return: 
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
END:VCARD
```

Thats all I have

Regards
Karl-Heinz

Comment: Please show us the entire program, not just the parts you think are relevant.  Do you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your code?  Also, I don't see in the output where it printed the return code.

Comment: I can't get Text::vCard to even install via CPAN without getting `BEGIN VCARD without matching END` errors.  Using ActivePerl 5.16 (64-bit) for Windows 8.1.  Active State's PPM installs it OK, but it doesn't include all the files that seem to be part of the module on CPAN.  Might be something wrong with the basic module...

Comment: Aye the module doesn't appear to be windows compatible.  Had similar install issues with Strawberry perl.

Answer (score 0):

This works (somewhat):

```
use 5.012;
use vCard;

my $v = vCard->new;
my $r = $v->load_file('v.vcf');
$r->other_names([]);
$r->honorific_prefixes([]);
$r->honorific_suffixes([]);
my $tmp = $r->as_string;
print "$tmp\n";
```

and prints

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:name;first;;;
FN:first name
ADR;TYPE=work:;;Strasse 1;Ortschaft arbeit;;56789;Deutschland
ADR;PREF=1;TYPE=home,pref:;;Strasse 2;Ortschaft 4;;12345;Deutschland
EMAIL:info@a.de
TEL;TYPE=work:+49 (0000) 123456
END:VCARD
```

anyway - bugged module...

When you use, the `load_file` method,

```
my $v = vCard->new;
my $r = $v->load_file('v.vcf');
```

instead of loading the file *into* current instance, it returns a *new vCard* instance. You can check this if you dump out the returned instances, for example with the `Data::Printer` module, like:

```
use 5.012;
use vCard;
use DDP;

my $v = vCard->new;
my $r =  $v->load_file('v.vcf'); #not loaded into $v, but returns a new instance
p $v; #dump the "original" $v
p $r; #dump the "new" $r
```

returns for the `$v`

```
vCard  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (22) : addresses, as_file, as_string, birthday, email_addresses, encoding_in, encoding_out, family_names, full_name, given_names, honorific_prefixes, honorific_suffixes, load_file, load_hashref, load_string, new, other_names, phones, photo, timezone, title, version
    private methods (8) : _build_address_nodes, _build_email_address_nodes, _build_name_node, _build_phone_nodes, _build_simple_nodes, _data, _setget, _simple_node_types
    internals: {
        _data          {
            version   4.0
        },
        encoding_in    "UTF-8",
        encoding_out   "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

for the $r

```
vCard  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (22) : addresses, as_file, as_string, birthday, email_addresses, encoding_in, encoding_out, family_names, full_name, given_names, honorific_prefixes, honorific_suffixes, load_file, load_hashref, load_string, new, other_names, phones, photo, timezone, title, version
    private methods (8) : _build_address_nodes, _build_email_address_nodes, _build_name_node, _build_phone_nodes, _build_simple_nodes, _data, _setget, _simple_node_types
    internals: {
        _data          {
            addresses            [
                [0] {
                    city        "Ortschaft arbeit",
                    country     "Deutschland",
                    extended    undef,
                    po_box      undef,
                    post_code   56789,
                    preferred   0,
                    region      undef,
                    street      "Strasse 1",
                    type        [
                        [0] "work"
                    ]
                },
                [1] {
                    city        "Ortschaft 4",
                    country     "Deutschland",
                    extended    undef,
                    po_box      undef,
                    post_code   12345,
                    preferred   1,
                    region      undef,
                    street      "Strasse 2",
                    type        [
                        [0] "home",
                        [1] "pref"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            email_addresses      [
                [0] {
                    address     "info@a.de",
                    preferred   0,
                    type        undef
                }
            ],
            family_names         [
                [0] "name"
            ],
            full_name            "first name",
            given_names          [
                [0] "first"
            ],
            honorific_prefixes   [
                [0] undef
            ],
            honorific_suffixes   [
                [0] undef
            ],
            other_names          [
                [0] undef
            ],
            phones               [
                [0] {
                    number      "+49 (0000) 123456",
                    preferred   0,
                    type        [
                        [0] "work"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            version              3.0
        },
        encoding_in    "UTF-8",
        encoding_out   "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

another problem with the module is, than after the load, the module cant work with the undefined values like

```
        honorific_prefixes   [
                [0] undef
            ],
```

therefore need initialize them with

```
$r->other_names([]);
$r->honorific_prefixes([]);
$r->honorific_suffixes([]);
p $r;
```

to

```
    honorific_prefixes   [],
```

As i tell, it is still a bit bugged module.

Comment: Hi; thanks - will give it a try. If this is buggy, can you recommend an other way to work on vcards (create, edit)?

Comment: i have tried the example with $v and $r but get an error:Continuation line, but no preceding line at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Text/vFile/asData.pm line 34